# Vb.net Journal Program Issue

Tags: vb.net, arrays, data-structures, streamreader, streamwriter

Okay so for an internship project i'm making a Journal with streamwriters and streamreaders.

I have to to where you can create an account with a name, Username, and Password. I also have it to where it creates a txt file in that persons name when you create the account. Now, they login and it brings them to the journal page. The Journal Page for the most part has a Date for your journal Entry, the title of the journal and the journal entry text itself.

The problem that I am having is that when you click the button to create/edit a journal entry, it goes through a sub routine that checks if that journal exists (Meaning that there is already one for that date) or not. If it doesn't exist, then it should create a new one at the bottom of the text file. If it does exist then it should edit the lines in which that journal are stationed in the text file.

Code:

```
Private Sub CreateBtn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CreateBtn.Click

    Errors = ""

    Dim TempCounter As Integer = 0

    If TitleTxt.Text = "" Then

        Errors = "You must enter a title." & vbCrLf

    End If


    If JournalTextRtxt.Text = "" Then

        Errors &= "You must enter an entry for the journal."

    End If

    If Errors <> "" Then

        MessageBox.Show("There's an error in creating/editing your journal." & vbCrLf & "Error(s):" & vbCrLf & Errors, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    Else

        JournalDate = DateTimePicker1.Value
        JournalTitle = TitleTxt.Text
        JournalText = JournalTextRtxt.Text

        arrJournalEntries(TempCounter).TheDate = JournalDate
        arrJournalEntries(TempCounter).Title = JournalTitle
        arrJournalEntries(TempCounter).JournalEntry = JournalText



        CheckAndWrite()

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub CheckAndWrite()

    Dim Reader As New StreamReader(MyName & ".txt", False)
    Dim Sline As String = Reader.ReadLine

    Counter = 0

    Do Until (Sline Is Nothing) 'Perform the code until the line in the text file is blank

        If Not Sline Is Nothing Then 'If the line in the text file is NOT blank then

            For i As Integer = 1 To 3

                Select Case i

                    Case 1

                        arrJournalEntries(Counter).TheDate = Sline
                        Sline = Reader.ReadLine


                    Case 2

                        arrJournalEntries(Counter).Title = Sline
                        Sline = Reader.ReadLine

                    Case 3

                        arrJournalEntries(Counter).JournalEntry = Sline
                        Sline = Reader.ReadLine

                End Select

            Next
        End If

        JournalDate = arrJournalEntries(Counter).TheDate

        Time = DateTimePicker1.Value

        MsgBox("Journal Date = " & JournalDate & vbCrLf & "Today's Date = " & Time)


        If Time = JournalDate Then

            JournalFound = True

        Else

            Counter += 1

            JournalFound = False

        End If

    Loop


    Reader.Close()

    Try

        If Sline Is Nothing Or JournalFound = False Then

            MsgBox("Your journal is now going to be created.")

            JournalDate = DateTimePicker1.Value
            JournalTitle = TitleTxt.Text
            JournalText = JournalTextRtxt.Text

            arrJournalEntries(Counter).TheDate = JournalDate
            arrJournalEntries(Counter).Title = JournalTitle
            arrJournalEntries(Counter).JournalEntry = JournalText

            Dim Writer As New StreamWriter(MyName & ".txt", True)

            Do Until (arrJournalEntries(Counter).TheDate = Nothing)

                Writer.WriteLine(arrJournalEntries(Counter).TheDate)
                Writer.WriteLine(arrJournalEntries(Counter).Title)
                Writer.WriteLine(arrJournalEntries(Counter).JournalEntry)


                Counter += 1

            Loop

            Writer.Close()


        End If

        If JournalFound = True Then

            MsgBox("Your journal is now going to be edited.")

            JournalDate = DateTimePicker1.Value
            JournalTitle = TitleTxt.Text
            JournalText = JournalTextRtxt.Text


            arrJournalEntries(Counter).TheDate = JournalDate
            arrJournalEntries(Counter).Title = JournalTitle
            arrJournalEntries(Counter).JournalEntry = JournalText


            Dim Writer As New StreamWriter(MyName & ".txt", True)

            Do Until (arrJournalEntries(Counter).TheDate = Nothing)

                Writer.WriteLine(arrJournalEntries(Counter).TheDate)
                Writer.WriteLine(arrJournalEntries(Counter).Title)
                Writer.WriteLine(arrJournalEntries(Counter).JournalEntry)


                Counter += 1

            Loop

            Writer.Close()


        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show("An error has occured" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Original Error:" & vbCrLf & ex.ToString)

    End Try



End Sub`
```

The problem that's occuring is that it's not only writing in the first time wrong. When it's supposed to say it's going to edit, it doesn't, it just says creating. But it just adds on to the file. After pressing the button 3 times with the current date. and the Title being "Test title", and the journal entry text being "Test text". This is what occured.

[image: Journal Entry Incorrect]

It should just be

7/10/2012 3:52:08 PM

Test title

Test text

7/10/2012 3:52:08 PM

Test title

Test text

the whole way through. but of course if it's the same date then it just overwrites it. So can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only filtering your array by the date, so it looks like you have an object with a date but no title or text:

```
Do Until (arrJournalEntries(Counter).TheDate = Nothing)
```

The "quick" fix:

```
Do Until (arrJournalEntries(Counter).TheDate = Nothing)
  If arrJournalEntries(Counter).Title <> String.Empty Then
    Writer.WriteLine(arrJournalEntries(Counter).TheDate)
    Writer.WriteLine(arrJournalEntries(Counter).Title)
    Writer.WriteLine(arrJournalEntries(Counter).JournalEntry)
  End If
  Counter += 1
Loop
```

Do consider getting rid of the array and using a `List(of JournalEntry)` instead.  Your code looks difficult to maintain in its current state.

Comment: Well see, the date is the only thing that needs to be checked if it is blank. The date will never be empty because i have a check against that. And I know my code looks difficult to maintain and it is right now. I'm just getting the basic functionality there so then i can clean it up and make it look nicer. Also, could you provide a link on these lists? Because i need it to be completely compatible with a structure.

Comment: @RichardPaulicelli Don't use a structure, use a class.  Then it's as simple as `Dim myEntries As New List(of JournalEntries)` where `JournalEntries` is your class with the date, title and text properties.  You won't need that `Counter` variable then.

Comment: thank you very much. When i'm done with this project i will try to use that and see how it does. But for now, i had just started using databases (I finally learned xD) but thank so much for your help!